# Customize Xcode snippet library

Tags: xcode, date, comments, code-snippets

Thank you for reading my question.

I want to customize my Xcode snippet library.

I've read this article.
http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/12/06/using-xcode-4-snippets/

Now I want to customize my comment that insert date(today) automatically after my comment text.

ex:

```
//This is my comment --- 2012/05/15
```

The date(2012/05/15) is automatically generate by Xcode.

Is this possible thing?

P.S. My Xcode version is 4.3.2

Thank you.

Comment: did you get the answer or any solution. Please post it here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Nikh141, unfortunately I haven't found any good enough solution for me.
Check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745605/add-time-and-date-in-custom-user-code-snippet-in-xcode
It may be helpful for you.

Comment: The link in the article no longer works. I think it's a good idea to edit the question in case there are new solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

As a snippet? Not possible. However, you can easily create a *Service* in *Automator* that calls `date +%Y-%m-%d`.